# Implementación de esta función matemática en Matlab

Tags: matemáticas, matlab, programación-funcional, codificación

Estoy teniendo algunos problemas para implementar la siguiente función:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para expresar la función inversa de phi(x) he calculado por mi cuenta en papel el caso correspondiente al primer trozo de la función.

Estoy teniendo que hacer algo mal, ya que el resultado debería ir siendo cada vez ''más positivo'' (mayor que cero) con cada iteración.

Os dejo aquí mi código:

```
l = [0 0.3078 0.27287 0 0 0 0.41933];
r = [0 0 0 0 0 0.4 0.6];

sigma = 0.8747;

mu0 = 2/sigma;

iterations = 50;

% Density evolution algorithm depiction for finding the treshold of irregular LDPC codes
syms x;

l_idle = zeros(1,length(l));
r_idle = zeros(1,length(r));

Q_1 = exp(-0.4527*x^0.86 + 0.0218);
Q_2 = sqrt(pi/x)*exp((-x/4)*(1-20/(7*x)));

mv = zeros(1,iterations+1);

for k=2:length(mv)
    for i = 1:length(l_idle)
        if ((mu0 + (i-1)*mv(k-1)) < 10) 
            l_idle(i) = double(subs(Q_1,x,(mu0 + (i-1)*mv(k-1))));
        else
             l_idle(i) = double(subs(Q_2,x,(mu0 + (i-1)*mv(k-1))));
        end
    end
    lambda = l*transpose(l_idle);    

    for j = 1:length(r_idle)
        b = 1-(1-lambda)^(j-1);
        if b < 10, r_idle(j) = subs(((log(x)-0.0218)/-0.4527)^(1/0.86),x,b);
        else,      r_idle(j) = subs(finverse(Q_2,x),x,b);
        end       
    end
    mv(k) = r*transpose(r_idle);
end
```

Mi problema es que la variable `r_idle(1)` es igual a `-Inf` cuando `b=0` dado `j=1`.

¿Sabéis cómo podría solucionar esto?

Muchas gracias de antemano, y que tengáis un buen día.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente había un problema con los índices. No se ve en esta foto, pero los sumatorios no empezaban desde `i, j = 1` sino desde `i, j = 2`. Al cambiar eso, todo funciona correctamente.

¡Muchas gracias por vuestra atención, y un saludo!